# Python CGI script: Mail Sender

Tags: python, sha1

I'm always getting this error while executing my py script

> File "mof.py", line 25
> for passwd in dictionary.read().split('\n'):
> ^
> IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level

Python Script

```
try:
    sha1 = raw_input("\t\n\nsha1 Hash:")

 
 
    try:
        dictionary = open("dictionary.txt","r")
    except(IOError):
        print "dictionary.txt not found!"
    for passwd in dictionary.read().split('\n'):
        if hashlib.sha1(passwd).hexdigest() == sha1:
           
            print("\n\t[OK]"+sha1+" : "+passwd+"\n")
            raw_input("Decrytion Success; Press Enter To Exit")

    else:
            print "\n\tFailed; Password not found in dictionary"
 

    except (KeyboardInterrupt):
    print "\n\t[+] Terminated by user"
```

Why?

Answer (score -1):

The `else:` line needs to be indented further.

Comment: Thnx and BTW you may already know the title is wrong :p, it's sHA1 decrypter script not a mail sender